# Java, MongoDB Convert Cursor to an Array

Tags: java, mongodb, loops, cursor

I'm using MongoDB with the Java driver.

I've written a query that finds the minimum year for each region in the data.

Full code:

```
public void minYearPerRegion() {
    for (int i = 0; i < uniqueRegions.size(); i++) {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Region", uniqueRegions.get(i));
        BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject("Year", 1)
                                                .append("Region", 1)
                                                .append("Population", 1);


        cursor = coll.find(query,field).sort(new BasicDBObject("Year",1)).limit(1);
        try {
            List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
            for (DBObject dbObject : cursor) {

                DBObject o = cursor.next();
                documents.add(o);
            }
            System.out.println("Document contains: " + documents.size() + " document/s");

        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }//end finally
    }//end for
}//end minYearPerRegion
```

I'm trying to store my findings as individual documents but the cursor seems to present it as object.
I've tried to split the object doing the following:

```
List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    for (DBObject dbObject : cursor) {
        DBObject o = cursor.next();
        documents.add(o);
    }
    System.out.println("Document contains: " + documents.size() + " document/s");
```

However the print line always says the documents list only contains one documents when it should contain 4 (as there are 4 unique regions).

Please tell me how to get each document individually from the cursor and store it in an Array or List.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `toArray()` which, intuitively, returns a `List<DBObject>`.  You're getting one document back because you passed `limit(1)` to the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my attempt. 
The problem was, the List `documents` was being emptied every time the for loop executed because of the line:

```
List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
```

To solve this I simply removed the List from the for loop like so:

```
public void minYearPerRegion() {
List<DBObject> documents = new ArrayList<DBObject>(); //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
for (int i = 0; i < uniqueRegions.size(); i++) {
    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Region", uniqueRegions.get(i));
    BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject("Year", 1)
                                            .append("Region", 1)
                                            .append("Population", 1);


    cursor = coll.find(query,field).sort(new BasicDBObject("Year",1)).limit(1);
    try {

        for (DBObject dbObject : cursor) {

            DBObject o = cursor.next();
            documents.add(o);
        }
        System.out.println("Document contains: " + documents.size() + " document/s");

    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }//end finally
}//end for
}//end minYearPerRegion
```